# язык С. указатели. ошибка инициализации

Tags: c, указатели, инициализация

задача:

1. Получить от пользователей три числа
2. Определить максимум и минимум (через использование отдельной функций)
3. вернуть значение максимума и минимум в основную функцию (через использование указателей)
4. Вывести на принт максимум и минимум

при попытке это сделать, появляется ошибка

Variable 'min' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
Аналогично про переменую max.

подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void maxmin(int prob1, int prob2, int prob3, int *max, int *min);

int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

    int *max, *min;

    maxmin(x, y, z, max, min);

    printf("%d%d", *max, *min);

    return 0;
}


void maxmin(int prob1, int prob2, int prob3, int *max, int *min)
{
    max = min = &prob1;
    
    if(prob2 > *max)
        max = &prob2;
    if(prob2 < *min)
        min = &prob2;
    
    if(prob3 > *max)
        max = &prob3;
    if(prob3 < *min)
        min = &prob3;    
}
```

Comment: при передаче в функцию переменные должны иметь какое-значение. С max и min  в этом коде такого не наблюдается.

Comment: @Эникейщик понял. спасибо. а какие значения нужно присвоить указателю, чтобы он "прошел" в функцию? Ставлю NULL, И появляется другая ошибка

Comment: @EOF то есть получается, max и min в main нужно обозначить как обычные перемены? 
Не как указатели?  
Но ведь в этом случае появляется ошибка 
"операнд "*" должен быть указателем, но имеет тип "int"" ... 
(относится к строке     printf("%d%d", *max, *min);

Answer (score 0):

Вот как будет работать:

```
void maxmin(int prob1, int prob2, int prob3, int *max, int *min);

int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    int max, min;
    maxmin(x, y, z, &max, &min);
    printf("%d  %d", max, min);

}


void maxmin(int prob1, int prob2, int prob3, int *max, int *min)
{
    *max = *min = prob1;
    
    if(prob2 > *max)
        *max = prob2;

    if(prob2 < *min)
        *min = prob2;
    
    if(prob3 > *max)
        *max = prob3;

    if(prob3 < *min)
        *min = prob3;
}
```

Comment: спасибо. заработало

Comment: Не сомневался :)

Comment: странно. но срабатывает даже если в основной функции сделать так: ;
    maxmin(x, y, z, max, min);....убрав знак &

Comment: Что-то вы не договариваете... https://ideone.com/5mjqY0

Comment: Я использую visual studio code... компилирую с флагами. gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra test_max2.c.   . Ошибка не появляется. И при запуске программы, тоже все работает корректно.

Comment: Ну ладно, раз вы утверждаете что все корректно — пишите так, как пишете. Тем дороже будут платить знающим людям :) Кстати, если вы на красный свет перебежали и не погибли — то как, вы делаете из этого вывод, что те, кто говорят, что надо на зеленый переходить — ничего не понимают, и что переход на красный свет — безопасно? :)